# What long-lasting continuity changes has The Simpsons undergone throughout the years?

Tags: continuity, the-simpsons

Rewatching *The Simpsons* recently has made me realise that there have been slightly more long-lasting changes in the show than I thought there were, though still not many. What major, long-lasting continuity changes have happened throughout the show?

By this, I mean things like Lisa becoming a vegetarian, Apu getting married, or Maude Flanders dying. Not things like Mr. Burns' casino getting destroyed - while nice to know, it's inconsequential as it's bought up only twice (when it's opened, then when it's shut).

Comment: This may be one of those things that isn't already answered; but is compiled here.  I don't have a full list, but I'll throw these out as three additional that come to mind.   Homer Was promoted to Safety Inspector in Season 1 (Homer's Odyssey) and has been so since.  Milhouse's parents are divorced in "A Milhouse Divided".  Smithers came out in "The Burns Cage" S27.

Comment: How many times should something be mentioned before it should count for an answer?

Comment: @user133469 lets go with an arbitrary 5, though most of these changes have a feeling of *intent* to be changes, though that is something to hard to quantify

Comment: What about Sideshow Bob no longer being Krusty's side... show.. guy

Comment: @komodosp him not being krustys sidekick is part of his introduction, so i wouldn't call it a continuity change.
His *introduction* might be as some characters like disco Stu are added like 7 seasons in, but thats probably falling outside the question scope

Comment: Krusty was introduced prior to his plan to frame Krusty.  He appeared in "The Telltale Head" which was prior to "Krusty Gets Busted"

Comment: @sonnik then mark me corrected, it would be a continuity change

Comment: What about Apu's children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Here's a few...

### Patty is out as gay

Patty Bouvier (one of Marge's sisters) has been out as lesbian since Season 16. You could argue that she always was a lesbian, but she started as closeted and became out.

### Moe is married

Moe Syzlak was married in Season 33. This is notable because his now-wife Maya was one of those temporary changes that gets undone so as *not* to change continuity and then later came back as a permanent continuity change.

### Comic Book Guy is married (Yes, *really*)

Comic Book Guy got married to Kumiko in Season 25, and she has been shown to still be his wife on multiple occasion since.

### Bleeding Gums Murphy died

Lisa's musical mentor died in Season 6. Not a really major character, but he appeared in at least 10 episodes.

### Rabbi Krustovsky died

Krusty's father Rabbi Krustovsky passed away in season 26. Again, not as much of a regular as Maude Flanders, but he appeared in a bunch of episodes.

Answer (score 0):

The death of Mona Simpson springs to mind. This was mentioned in multiple episodes after the fact.

Comment: It's a TV show, it's it self referencing? It's in the actual episodes, not in additional material.